# Tag followed by link results in unexpected formatting

Tags: bug, tags, markdown, hyperlinks, markdown-rendering

```
This is a [tag:tag] [and link][1].  It displays incorrectly.
```

This is a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tag) [and link][1](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334552/tag-followed-by-link-results-in-unexpected-formatting).  It displays incorrectly.

```
This is a [tag:tag]&nbsp;[and link][1].  It displays correctly.
```

This is a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tag) [and link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334552/tag-followed-by-link-results-in-unexpected-formatting).  It displays correctly.

Comment: Duplicate of [New “[tag:” syntax interferes with Markdown links](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70529/new-tag-syntax-interferes-with-markdown-links) on MSE.  It was marked as [tag:status-bydesign].  *(Huh, even though there's [a "status-bydesign" tag on Meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/status-bydesign), trying to link to it goes to the (non-existent tag) on SO.  Weird.)

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor: You probably want `[meta-tag:status-bydesign]`, which does link correctly: [meta-tag:status-bydesign]. Child meta tags can only accessed with that syntax.

Comment: @nathantuggy that's what I was missing.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Duplicate of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70529/new-tag-syntax-interferes-with-markdown-links, as noted by @Joshua Taylor.  Cannot close questions as dupes from other sites, so I'm posting and accepting this to tie up the loose end.