# Square brackets before a link cause incorrect link parsing

Tags: support, markdown, hyperlinks, markdown-rendering

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53960873/4922375), I tried to write a sentence

> Use [java-10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-10) [local variable type inference][1](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/286) ...

but it didn't get parsed well, so I had to add an extra space after the tag

> Use [java-10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-10)  [local variable type inference](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/286) ...

I've checked some other scenarios.

1. [] [text][1](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/286)
2. [java-10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-10) [text][1](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/286)
3. [java-10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-10)  [text](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/286)

It appears that `[]` before a link cause the issue.

```
1. [] [text][1]  
2. [tag:java-10] [text][1]  
3. [tag:java-10]  [text][1]
```

Comment: A way to sidestep the problem: I would not use the tag there. I'd just write, "Use Java 10's [local variable type inference](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/286)." The tag is not going to lead them to any info that's particularly useful for what you're trying to explain.

Comment: Duplicates: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334552/tag-followed-by-link-results-in-unexpected-formatting and https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70529/new-tag-syntax-interferes-with-markdown-links

Answer (score 14):

Markdown need escaping:

> ```
> [] [text][1]
> ```
>
> [] [text][1](https://stackoverflow.com)

The right way to do this:

> ```
> \[\] [text][1]
> ```
>
> [] [text](https://stackoverflow.com)

It's true even for tags (well I'm surprised too)

> ```
> \[tag:javascript\] [text][1]
> ```
>
> [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) [text](https://stackoverflow.com)

In fact, you don't need to escape the closing bracket:

> ```
> \[tag:python] [text][1]
> ```
>
> [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) [text](https://stackoverflow.com)

Comment: I don't want to escape them, they are the part of the syntax `[tag:TAG_NAME]`

Comment: you mean `\[tag:java-10\] [text][1] ` is a valid construction?

Comment: @AndrewTobilko See update, really surprising.

Comment: Yes, it works, thank you. It looks like I should escape either bracket (at least one of them), not only the closing one

Comment: O_o Wat. Why would as *escaped* bracket (`\[tag:javascript\]` be rendered as the tag thing? *thinks* ...Is link generation a post-Markdown thing?

Comment: Putting an HTML comment between them (like `<!-- -->`) also seems to work.

Comment: @jpmc26 That appears to be the case.

Comment: The question is whether Markdown really needs escaping, or if you found an unlucky workaround. Which Markdown specification says that escaping is needed?

Answer (score 7):

So this is a conflict between tags (which are not Markdown syntax) and standard Markdown syntax.

Note that Markdown links allow a space between the label and the reference:

```
[link] [1]

[1]: http://example.com
```

which renders as<sup>1</sup>:

[link](http://example.com)

And, as Markdown parses left-to-right, the Markdown parser sees the tag followed by a link and assumes the tag is the first half of a reference style link. However, as no reference matches, then Markdown ignores the reference link and continues after the end of the reference. Of course, what Markdown say as a reference was actually intended to be the label of the link. So it starts back up with the actual reference, which does exist. And as Markdown allows for single reference style links (the label and reference is one and the same), it sees that reference as a link and processes it.

The point is that from a Markdown perspective, this is totally expected behavior. Thus the suggestion to escape the tag. Escaping the tag causes Markdown to not see it as part of a link (two spaces accomplish the same thing).  The Markdown parser then picks up after the tag and now correctly pairs the label and reference parts of the link. And with the escape characters removed by Markdown, the postprocessor can recognize it as a tag and handle it appropriately.

So, the question is: how can SO fix this so that Markdown does not incorrectly recognize a tag as part of a link? I see a few options, none of which are great:

1. Change the syntax for marking up tags.
2. Alter the Markdown parser in some way:

   - Remove the allowance for a space between label and reference.
   - Extend the markdown parser to natively parse tags.
3. Some other backward-incompatable change I haven't thought of.

<sup>1</sup> Weirdly, the space between label and reference does not work within a quoteblock. In that case, it is not recognized as a link. Thus, I did not use a quoteblock above.